# How do I include negative numbers in xticks, using matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```py
df = [4, -1, 5, -32, 4, -32, -1]
```

I want to set the `xticks` like this:

```py
tick_locs = [-30, -10, 0, 10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000]
plt.xticks(tick_locs, tick_locs)
```

That gives me a weird graph:
[image]

I can set the ticks to all positive, but that won't give me negative numbers on the x-axis:

```py
tick_locs = [10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000]
plt.xticks(tick_locs, tick_locs)
```

[image]

Any idea how to get the negative ticks marks?

P.S. The data is set up as logged, but the x-axis is set to show the actual numbers:

```
bin_edges = 10 ** np.arange(-0.1, np.log10(planes_df['ArrDelay'].max())+0.1, 0.1)
plt.hist(planes_df['ArrDelay'], bins = bin_edges)
plt.xscale('log')
tick_locs = [10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000]
plt.xticks(tick_locs, tick_locs)
```

Comment: Are you trying to show negative numbers on a logarithmic scale? How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Also, including 0 in a logscale create problems

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest see the addition above.

Comment: Maybe you can explain in your own words where on a logarithmic scale you would expect negative numbers to show up and why.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I can't explain how. Should I just not use a histogram? I can display this as a bar chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the line `plt.xscale('log')`. This will make the x-axis scale linear. A logarithmic axis cannot display non-positive values, as `log(x)` is undefined for `x <= 0`.